# ItemClickListener não disponível

Tags: android

estou criando um projeto o qual mostra uma listagem de equipamentos através de uma RecyclerView. Ao clicar em algum item dessa RecyclerView, precisaria que fosse aberta uma nova tela com detalhes do item clicado. O problema é que não aparece a opção itemClickListener, mesmo estando declarado no viewHolder.

ViewHolder

```
public class InventarioViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    public TextView txtHd, txtHostName, txtMarca, txtMemoria, txtModelo, txtPcId, txtProcessador, txtSetor, txtSo, txtTipo, txtUsuario;
    public ImageView img_user, menu_options;

    private ItemClickListener itemClickListener;

    public InventarioViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

         txtPcId = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pc_nome);
         txtUsuario = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pc_usuario);
         txtSetor = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pc_setor);

         img_user = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_user);
         menu_options = itemView.findViewById(R.id.menu_options);



         itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        itemClickListener.onClick(view, getAdapterPosition(), false);

    }
}
```

Home.class

```
private void loadInventario() {
        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Inventario, InventarioViewHolder>(Inventario.class,
                R.layout.inventario_item, InventarioViewHolder.class, categories) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(InventarioViewHolder viewHolder, Inventario model, int position) {
                viewHolder.txtPcId.setText(model.getPcId());
                viewHolder.txtUsuario.setText(model.getUsuario());
                viewHolder.txtSetor.setText(model.getSetor());

                Picasso.with(Home.this).load(model.getImage()).into(viewHolder.img_user);


    //***********************  Após o viewHolder. deveria aparecer a opção setItemClickListener  *******************
                viewHolder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener()){

                }




            }
        };
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        recycler_inventario.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

RecyclerView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Home">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_inventario"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_playlist_add_black_24dp"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Layout da RecyclerView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp">

    <View
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_height="0.6dp"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_user"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_account_circle_black_24dp" />


        </LinearLayout>



        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pc_nome"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@color/overlayBackground"
                android:text="000000"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pc_usuario"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@color/overlayBackground"
                android:text="Nome do usuário"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pc_setor"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@color/overlayBackground"
                android:text="Setor"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />



        </LinearLayout>



    </LinearLayout>



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="350dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menu_options"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_more_vert_black_24dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>




</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Não aparece porque sua classe `InventarioViewHolder` não tem o método. Pelo menos no código que você postou só está declarada a variável `itemClickListener`. Cadê o setter?

Comment: Obrigado Piovezan.. Era isso mesmo!

Comment: @vsousa tirou meu "aceito" ;-;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crie essa classe em seu projeto:

```
public class RecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position);

        public void onLongItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

    GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

    public RecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
                if (child != null && mListener != null) {
                    mListener.onLongItemClick(child, recyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(child));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
        View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if (childView != null && mListener != null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            mListener.onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) { }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent (boolean disallowIntercept){}
}
```

Após isso vá na sua activity onde está o recycler view e faça(Após já ter aplicado o adapter, claro):

```
mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(Main.this, mRecyclerView ,new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(View view, int i) {
                     //Na view você pode recuperar os componentes em cada item 
                     //Do recycler view, tipo:  view.findviewById(R.id.minhaImagem);

                  //int i é igual a posição da lista, se você sabe a posição 
                //pode recuperar todos os itens da sua lista de objetos
                }

                @Override
                public void onLongItemClick(View view, int i) {
                     //O mesmo pra o onLong
                }
            })
        );
```

Assim você tem um controle melhor do seu RecyclerView